# Piwik tracking more events than GoogleAnalytics

Tags: google-analytics, matomo

I have a event that is fired in Piwik and Google Analytics when the pages loads. The event is firing something like "The product was viewed". However, I have a discrepancy between the numbers, in general 9% of difference.

- I have the average of 100k events by day.
- The server are configured

  - Load balance
  - Redis
  - All optimisations.
- I am firing the Google without noninteraction/beacon flag. Can it be a
  problem?

Answer (score 1):

Problems can be caused by:

- Limit: 500 hits per session
- Tracking blockers restricting only GA
- Different time of Piwik and UA script execution
- Sampling

But do not try to compare two different technologies, you will probably newer have exactly same data. Rather learn about limits and differencies.